# React js update current time works properly but throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my js React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyNav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        count: 0,
        time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    };

    this.countUp = this.countUp.bind(this);
    this.tm = this.tm(this);
}

countUp() {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count+1,
    })
}

tm() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
            time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
        })
    }, 1000)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className='myNav'>
                <li> menu1</li>
                <li> menu2</li>
                <li> {this.props.title}</li>
                <li>{this.state.count}</li>
                <li>{this.state.time}</li>
                <button onClick={this.countUp}> I'm a button </button>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default MyNav
```

I set up a timer so that it updates the current time every second.
It seems to render succesfully but throws the following error in console:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is 
not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. 
Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property 
with the desired state in the MyNav component.
```

I think it throws the error cause I'm not really using the tm function?? But I don't know how can I possibly use that in my render() function... can anyone tell me what'd be the best way to do this and avoid the error?

Comment: `this.tm = this.tm(this);` you forgot `bind` it should be `this.tm = this.tm.bind(this);`

Comment: @AlanOmar I did it and the timer stopped updating the time on the webpage. Do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: add `componentDidMount` to your component, and call `tm` from there.
`componentDidMount (){this.tm();}`